# How to specify control's property according to platform in xaml code?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Suppose I have a `TextBlock`, on PC, I want it text is "PC", and on Xbox, it shows "XBox".

So how to distinguish platform in xaml code, not in C# code.

The reason I have to do this is because there is some controls defined in styles, I want them differs between platforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [WindowsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/Markup/OnDevice.cs), this extension that meet your requirements: `OnDevice Markup Extension`.

Use like this:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{helpers:OnDevice Default=Hi, Desktop=Hello, Xbox=World}"
              xmlns:helpers="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions.Markup"/>
```

In addition, in `WindowsCommunityToolkit`, there is `SystemInformation.DeviceFamily` to help you determine the current device type.

Best regards.